# How to get default value in dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a drop down list and it has two values. if user didn't select none of the value it should set a default value.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="abc.code" required>
  <option ng-repeat="x in codeList" value="{{x}}" ng-selected="codeList[1]" >
      {{x}} </option>
</select>
```

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like this 
`<option value="didnt select" selected hidden>please select one option</option>`

for default value statically in your select input

Comment: you cant have only two options and somehow magically choose the third one it's not possible this is the only way if you set this option with hidden and selected attributes it will act like it's just a placeholder for the select but also has a default value and because of hidden attribute you wont see it in options list

Comment: adding an option for just the default value is the only way and using the selected and hidden attributes arethe neatest way to do this

Comment: i need to choose option from among those two options in select list. as an example there are A and B in list. I need to choose A as default.

Comment: ok then you should use this

  `<option ng-repeat="x in codeList" value="{{x}}" ng-selected="$first? true: false">`

you can read more about it in 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat